# error: incompatible types: LinkedList2.Node cannot be converted to Node

Tags: java

I have a question about my code.
when I complied the code bellow, it didn't work and would be error.

LinkedListIndex2.java:62: error: incompatible types: LinkedList2.Node cannot be converted to Node
        Node found = KthToLast(ll.getFirst(), k);
                                          ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

I can't find how to solve this error. please give me the way how to revise the code and the reason!.

Thank you!

```
class LinkedList2{

Node header;

static class Node{
    int data;
    Node next = null;
}

LinkedList2(){
    header = new Node();
}

void append(int d){
    Node end = new Node();
    end.data = d;
    Node n = header;
    while (n.next != null){
        n = n.next;
    }
    n.next = end;
}

void delete(int d){
    Node n = header;
    while ( n.next != null){
        if(n.next.data == d){
            n.next = n.next.next;
        }else {
            n = n.next;
        }
    }
}

void retrieve(){
    Node n = header.next;
    while(n.next != null){
        System.out.print(n.data + "->");
        n = n.next;
    }
    System.out.println(n.data);
}

Node getFirst() {
    return header.next;
  }
}

public class LinkedListIndex2{

public static void main (String[] args){
    LinkedList2 ll = new LinkedList2();
    ll.append(1);
    ll.append(2);
    ll.append(3);
    ll.append(4);
    ll.retrieve();
    ll.delete(1);
    ll.retrieve();

    int k =2;
    Node found = KthToLast(ll.getFirst(), k);
    System.out.println(found.data);
}
private static Node KthToLast(Node first, int k) {
    Node p1 = first;
    Node p2 = first;

    for(int i =0; i < k; i++){
        if(p1 == null) return null;
        p1 = p1.next;
    }

    while ( p1 != null){
        p1 = p1.next;
        p2 = p2.next;
    }
    return p2;
  }
}
```

Comment: You've declared `Node` as a class nested within `LinkedList2`, but you're trying to refer to it from `LinkedListIndex2` as if it were a top-level type, so you're probably importing a different `Node` class from somewhere. You could either change your code to refer to that (`LinkedList2.Node found = ...`) or make it *not* a nested type.

Comment: Thank you. I understrand what you mean. I convert 'Node' to 'LinkedList2.Node' in 'LinkedListIndex2 class', so it works. @JonSkeet